# Using DNSMasq, how do I provide a single static route for an IPv6 network?

Tags: ipv6, dnsmasq

Assuming I am running two Dual stack IPv4/IPv6 networks:

- Network 1: Internet connected

  - IPv4 - 192.0.2.0/24 provides a default route via 192.0.2.1
  - IPv6 - 2001:db8::0/64 provides a default route via 2001:db8::1
- Network 2: Static assets

  - IPv4 - 198.51.100.0/24 provides a route via 198.51.100.1 to 203.0.113.0/24
  - IPv6 - 2001:db8:1::0/64 provides a route via 2001:db8:1::1 to 2001:db8:2::0/64

In a pure IPv4 network, the relevant stanzas in my dnsmasq.conf files for the two networks look like this:

```
# Network 1 IPv4
dhcp-range=192.0.2.2,192.0.2.254,2h
dhcp-option=option:router,192.0.2.1
```

```
# Network 2 IPv4
dhcp-range=198.51.100.2,198.51.100.254,2h
dhcp-option=option:router # Disables "default" route advert
dhcp-option=option:classless-static-route,203.0.113.0/24,198.51.100.1
```

I can configure my IPv6 network to provide these parts too, at least in Network 1, like this:

```
# Network 1 IPv6
dhcp-range=::2,::FFFF:FFFF:FFFF:FFFF,constructor:eth1,ra-names,slaac,2h
ra-enable
```

How can I define a single "static" route advertised over DHCPv6 (or similar), or is this not something I can do with IPv6?

Answer (score 0):

DHCPv6 can not be used because DHCPv6 provides no option similar to option 121/classless-static-route, see https://www.iana.org/assignments/dhcpv6-parameters/dhcpv6-parameters.xhtml

Use RA. For instance with bird2 and protocol RADV, see https://bird.network.cz/?get_doc&v=20&f=bird-6.html#ss6.11
I assume any other radvd will do, too.